# Rails carrierwave mounting on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I need to mount picture uploader after some verification function.

But if I call as usual mounting uploader in model:

```
mount_uploader :content, ContentUploader
```

carrierwave first download content, and then Rails start verification of model.

Specifically, I don't want to load big files at all! I want to check http header `Content-length` and `Content-type` and then, if it's OK, mount uploader.

Maybe something like that:

```
if condition
  mount_uploader :content, ContentUploader
end
```

How can I do it?

P.S. Rails version 3.2.12

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to go if you just want avoid loading big files! That said, one can have conditional mount overriding `content=`.

As CarrierWave v1.1.0 there is still no conditional mount. But note that `mount_uploader` first [includes a module](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L138) in the class and then [overrides](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L363) the original `content=` to call the method `content=` [defined](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L145) in the included module. So, a workaround is just to redefine the accessors **after** you have called `mount_uploader`:

```rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :content, ContentUploader

    def content=(arg)
        if condition
            super
        else
            # original behavior
            write_attribute(:content, arg)
        end
    end

    def content
        # some logic here
    end
end
```